# Aligning p:inputText with labels

Tags: html, css, primefaces

Hello there I have a short question why this wont work.
I want to do excatly what you see in the first example but with Primefaces. 
When I do it like this it all works good in terms of styling it but for usage I would like to go with Primefaces. But when I do the same just with p:inputText instead of just input it just wont work.

```css
.labels {
    float:left;
    line-height:1.7em;
    padding-right:2em;
}
.inputs {
    line-height:1.7em
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div class="labels">
    <label>Label1</label><br/>
    <label>Label2</label><br/>
    <label>Label3</label><br/>
  </div>
  <div class="inputs">
    <input type="text" id="inpput1" value=""/><br/>
    <input type="text" id="inpput2" value=""/><br/>
    <input type="text" id="inpput3" value=""/><br/>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Here is how it looks with Prime Faces.

```css
.labels {
    float:left;
    line-height:1.7em;
    padding-right:2em;
}
.inputs {
    line-height:1.7em
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div class="labels">
    <label>label1</label><br/>
    <label>label2</label><br/>
    <label>label3</label><br/>
  </div>
  <div class="inputs">
    <p:inputText id="test1" value=""/><br/>
    <p:inputText id="test2" value=""/><br/>
    <p:inputText id="test3" value=""/><br/>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to figure it out myself.

I used h:PanelGrid to align all labels and Textfields.

here is a short example of it.

```html
<h:panelGrid column="2">
  <label>label1</label>
  <p:inputText/>
  <label>label2</label>
  <p:inputText/>
  <label>label3</label>
  <p:inputText/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

This is not excecuteable here but it works in Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

did you include the libraries? your code is seems to be correct.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<fieldset>
  <div class="labels">
    <label>label1</label><br/>
    <label>label2</label><br/>
    <label>label3</label><br/>
  </div>
  <div class="inputs">
    <p:inputText id="test1" value=""/><br/>
    <p:inputText id="test2" value=""/><br/>
    <p:inputText id="test3" value=""/><br/>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Yes I did add the Library but it still does not work.

Comment: did you check in the developer tool (browser console) if there is any error or if the libraries are included. maybe you have to clear your browsercache.

Comment: @Gabbax0r: Form how I read the question, the inputs are shown (so the libraries are included etc) but the alignment is just off. Pure css issue in relation to how the OP wants his html to be (kind of unusual)